# GIT: Find a file in a specific commit

Tags: git, search, tree

I have a file name - for example "MapControl.ascx"

The project is complex in tree structure. I'd like to perform simple search in the file tree WITHOUT the need to checkout.

I could just checkout that commit to my working dir and use simple Windows CTRL+F ... but I'm a lazy programmer and I believe there must be a better way.

For example: `git magic_search_file_in_commit "MapControl.ascx" "commit_sha1_hash"`

would output a list like this:

- `/folderA/folderB/MapControl.ascx`
- `/anotherfolder/MapControl.ascx`
- `/yetanotherfolder/folder/folder/MapControl.ascx`

Any or all of these paths might have been deleted in future commits but that should not matter, the files existed in the commit I want.

How would I do that in GIT? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r <commit-hash> | grep "MapControl.ascx"
```